# Jquery Datatables sort column border color

Tags: datatables

I have a need to style my (striped) data table's sorted column so that it has an outline around the column (ie: the 1st row's border top and last row's border bottom are colored as well as the border sides for every column).

When I use the .sorting{} class and give it a background color it works, when I try to simply give it a border color without the 1st row and last row requirements I cant get that to work.

Works

```
.sorting_1{background:red}
```

Doesn't work

```
.sorting_1{border: 2px solid red}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The border that was already established by the table-bordered class was interfering with what I wanted to do, so I ended up doing the following which kept my overall borders but put the borders around the sorted column and border top and border bottom around the first and last row of the column.

```
.sorting_1{
border-left: 2px solid cornflowerblue !important;
border-right: 2px solid cornflowerblue !important;
}

.table-bordered > tbody > tr:first-child > td[class*="sorting_1"]{
border-top: 2px solid cornflowerblue !important;
}

.table-bordered >tbody > tr:last-child > td[class*="sorting_1"]{
border-bottom: 2px solid cornflowerblue !important;
}
```